# Pivot not returning aggregate (SQL Adventureworks)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the Adventureworks sample database (`HumanResources.Employee` table is the database).

For simplicity I will take a sample of the table:

```
HireDate       Gender        SalariedFlag
-----------------------------------------
2014-01-01         M              1
2015-01-30         F              1
2014-01-30         M              1
2014-02-12         F              0
2014-03-11         F              1 and so on
```

Code:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(hiredate), F, M 
FROM
    HumanResources.employee
PIVOT
    (sum(SalariedFlag) 
         FOR gender IN ([F], [M])
    ) AS gg
  -- Unable to use sum though since its bit field
```

Expected output:

```
Year      F     M
-------------------
2014      1     2    # count(SalariedFlag) 
2015      1     0    # count(SalariedFlag)
```

But I really get:

```
No name     F               M
-------------------------------
2014         0              1
2015         1              0
2014         0              1
2014         1              0
2014         1              0
```

and so on.

So basically in output its not considering the `salariedflag` column at all, it is simply returning 1 in F if the person was female and 1 in M if person was male.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, counting the value of `SalariedFlag` isn't going to achieve anything. `COUNT` *counts* the number of rows with a non-`NULL` value, and all your rows have a non-`NULL` value. Instead you want to `COUNT` the number of rows where the value of `SalariedFlag` is `1`.

You *might*, therefore, be able to `SUM` the column, however, as it's a "flag" it's more likely to be a `bit` and you can't `SUM` a `bit`. Therefore using `COUNT` and checking the value is `1` with a `CASE` would likely be better.

Personally, rather than using the restrictive `PIVOT` operator, I would suggest you use conditional aggregation. This gives you the following:

```sql
SELECT YEAR(HireDate) AS HireYear,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' AND SalariedFlag = 1 THEN 1 END) AS M,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' AND SalariedFlag = 1 THEN 1 END) AS F
FROM #YourTable
GROUP BY YEAR(HireDate);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=555a82060d92348ee2b762d194828d4c)